# Prolog help removing or skipping an item whilst appending

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, logic

How do you skip a specific word if its part of a list and then append the rest? 
Usually this item is at the start of the list and sometimes it isn't so how would I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to delete the first occurrence of an element in a list? You can use [selectchk/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=selectchk/3).

Comment: how do I delete the item then append the rest though im not sure I have this code

myappend([],[]).
myappend([Head|Rest],[det(Head)|Output]):- noun(Head), myappend(Rest,Output).

Comment: selectchk/3 does just that. If you want to do it yourself, you must distinguish the two cases: Either it is the item you want to remove, or it isn't. Then, depending on whether it is, the "resulting" list will look different, and this must be reflected in your code. You can for example use if-then-else (If -> Then ; Else ) to distinguish the cases. It could look like: ( skip(Head) -> Result = Rest ; Result = [Head|Remaining], my_append(Rest, Remaining) )

Answer (score 0):

```
'skip a specific word if its part of a list and then append the rest. Usually this item is at the start of the list and sometimes it isn't so'(_item,_list,_rest) :-
  append(L1,[_item|L2],_list),append(L1,L2,_rest),!.
```